# android 3.0 fragment transition animation

Tags: android, animation, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

I am working on an aplication for Adroid honeycomb 3.0 where I want to animate the changing of fragment with a slide_in slide_out. I first used the comapatibility library but the performamce was disapointing, so I left that. The 3.0 Api seems to work differently and my code ended up in ForceClose crashes.

Is there an example on how to do the fragment animations without the compatibility lib. The transactionmanager.setcustomanimation does not work. in the anim xml I use the translate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry very old post and you probably figured it out by now; but for future reference if you use the compatibility library you must use the standard animation in setCustomAnimation() (translate, scale ect etc.), while if you use an SDK with native support for the FragmentManager then your animation must use the objectAnimator animation.